# Video and audio mixer with audio recording capability using nodejs

Tags: node.js, audio, video, audio-recording, mixer

How can I make a video and audio mixer with audio recording capability using nodejs.
Also I want an editable waveform graph of audio.
Is there any supporting package in nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are lucky enough to find a package that does exactly what you want, I suspect that using ffmpeg through a nodes wrapper of interface library such as the one below will be the easiest approach:

- https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

This allows you use all the power and large user community behind the ffmpeg command line program, but wrapped in a node.js friendly interface.