# Is it possible to merge two videos in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, video, video-processing

I am using Nodejs and Kurento in order to create a videoconference. Thanks to Kurento I am able to record the two endpoints video but now I want to be able to create a video that has video1's video and audio and video2's audio, one of top of the other so that you can hear the two points of the conversation.

Is there any library in node that may help me? I know jitsi-meet uses jibrid for something similar and I would prefer to find an alternative before having to migarte to jitsi.

Comment: I think you have to use ffmeg, look at the npm list : https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ffmpeg

Comment: I used fluent-ffmpeg two join them (one after the other) but don't know how to do exactly what I want, any idea?

Comment: try this library --> https://github.com/ArsalanDotMe/VideoStitch

Comment: Ok I found a library for video mixing : https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898830/video-and-audio-mixer-with-audio-recording-capability-using-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I have done is use Nodejs child_process.exec to execute ffmpeg command in the command shell